# print an underscore character in place of integer 0

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, cs50

I am making the game of fifteen and thus implementing the draw function which prints out the board on the terminal. My function goes as follow:

```
void draw(void)
{
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] != 0)
            {
                printf("%2d ", board[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" _ ");
            }
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Its working fine for board upto 3X3 but for the board of 4X4 it prints out the following:

[image: output]

In the second column of the second row it prints 1 whereas I expect it to print 10.

Comment: Why aren't you passing parameters to the function? Using global variables is something you should learn to avoid from the beginning. As more inexperienced you are the more dangerous global variables are, yet inexpert programmers use them a lot more than experts.

Comment: Actually, [that's not what your code prints.](http://ideone.com/nVOJCP) Please provide the *exact* code that you're having problems with, and describe clearly what's wrong with its output.

Comment: You don't actually state a question.

Comment: Also, I think it's working fine with a 3x3 board. What exactly is wrong with the 4x4? do you need to change to `"%3d"`?

Comment: @iharob in the second column in the second row it prints 1 whereas I expect it to print 10

Comment: You did not show how you numbered the board in the first place. Is the first `2` meant be `5`?

Comment: @WeatherVane the numbers are placed by another function. I'll update it

Comment: im very sorry i updated the code and its working.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the maximum length of a cell number, and use that to format the `printf`.

```
char numstr[20];
int maxlen = sprintf(numstr, "%d", d * d - 1);
...
printf("%*d ", maxlen, board[i][j]);
...
printf("%*c ", maxlen, '_');
```